# Azure Cloud Shell

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

For writing, running, and debugging code with just a browser, and a sample Node.js Web App as in the following **Code Snippet**:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Node.js Version: " + process.version + "\n");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port: ${port}`);
});
```

**Azure Cloud Shell Output:**

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000
Node.js Version: v16.20.2
```

**Azure Cloud Shell Web Preview** opens:
https://ux.console.azure.com//proxy/3000/
only to show this error:

**Cannot GET /proxy/3000/**

After the following steps:

1. Configure port to preview
   Valid ports include [1025-8079] and [8091-49151]
2. 3000
3. Open and browse

What's missing?

Comment: After multiple trial and error, I concluded it as a BUG and raised a Github Bug Issue with the Cloud shell, Refer the Github Issue here, Where I have given what all I tried in detail- https://github.com/Azure/CloudShell/issues/368 > Keep an eye on this bug request for the further updates until it gets resolved